# Sharepoint Online Calculated Column Differences

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error

I have 2 columns, 1 that has a calculated date depending on another column. Call that Date 1.
Second Column is another Calculated column. it looks at Date 1 and checks if its overdue.

The issue is there is multiple rows of Items overdue that say "Current". the same forumla works on one row then makes a mistake in the next? doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I created two Date and Time columns named [Date 1] and [Due Date] in the list.

Then, I created a Calculated column named [Cal1] to check if [Date1] is out of date (compare with [Due Date]).

**Formula:**

```
=IF([Date 1]<[Due Date],"Expired","Valid")
```

[image]

[image]